# Multiple modals with different content inside in one page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create multiple modals in a page, but they have different content inside of them. However, I'm not sure how to do this. I am new to Javascript which is why I'm having trouble doing this. I'm being able to open modals but they all have the same content inside them. I'm trying to make each model have different contents.

HTML:

```
<div class = "members-grid">
    <button data-modal-target = "#modal" class = "open"><img src = "eunbi.jpg" alt = "kwon eunbi" class = "size"></button>
    <button data-modal-target = "#modal" class = "open"><img src = "sakura.jpg" alt = "miywaki sakura" class = "size"></button>
</div>


<div class = "modal" id = "modal">
    <div class = "modal-img">
   <img src = "eunbi.jpg" alt = "kwon eunbi" class = "modal-size">
   <ul class = "profile-info">
       <li class = "name">Kwon Eunbi</li>
       <li class = "text-style">Birthday: September 27, 1995</li>
       <li class = "text-style">Position: Leader, Main Dancer, Lead Vocalist</li>
       <li class = "text-style">Rank: 7</li>
   </ul>
    </div>
</div>
            
<div class = "modal" id = "modal">
    <div class = "modal-img">
    <img src = "sakura.jpg" alt = "miyawaki sakura" class = "modal-size">
    <ul class = "profile-info">
            <li class = "name">Miyawaki Sakura</li>
            <li class = "text-style">Birthday: March 19, 1998</li>
            <li class = "text-style">Position: Sub Vocalist, Sub Rapper, Visual</li>
            <li class = "text-style">Rank: 2</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
        const openModalButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-modal-target]')
        const closeModalButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-close-button]')
        const overlay = document.getElementById('overlay')

        openModalButtons.forEach(button => {
          button.addEventListener('click', () => {
            const modal = document.querySelector(button.dataset.modalTarget)
            openModal(modal)
          })
        })

        overlay.addEventListener('click', () => {
          const modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal.active')
          modals.forEach(modal => {
            closeModal(modal)
          })
        })

        overlay.addEventListener('click', () =>{
            const modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal.active')
            modal.forEach(modal => {
                closeModal(modal)
                })
            })

        closeModalButtons.forEach(button => {
          button.addEventListener('click', () => {
            const modal = button.closest('.modal')
            closeModal(modal)
          })
        })

        function openModal(modal) {
          if (modal == null) return
          modal.classList.add('active')
          overlay.classList.add('active')
        }

        function closeModal(modal) {
          if (modal == null) return
          modal.classList.remove('active')
          overlay.classList.remove('active')
        }
```

CSS

```
.open{
background: none;
color: inherit;
border: none;
padding: 0;
font: inherit;
cursor: pointer;
outline: inherit;
}

.modal{
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
border: 1px solid black;
background: white;
z-index: 10;
width: 900px;
max-width: 80%;
}

.modal-img{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}


.modal.active{
transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}

.close-button{
background: none;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
outline: none;
font-size: 1.25rem;
font-weight: bold;
}

#overlay{
position: fixed;
opacity: 0;
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
pointer-events: none;
}

#overlay.active{
pointer-events: all;
opacity: 1;
}

.modal-size{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: To start with: Both modal `divs` have the same `id`. You can't do that. They must be unique.

Comment: @RobMoll after that what should I do?

Comment: Where/how are you getting the modal data (for example: Birthday: September 27, 1995). Is it static or do you fetch it from the server, etc.?

Comment: @RobMoll It's static

Comment: I would place the "static" data in an array of objects. Use only 1 modal. Use the `.filter` method and the `.map` method to build the `<img>` and `<ul><li>` html and append the result to `<div class = "modal-img">`. Show the modal.

Comment: @RobMoll If you could show me a sample code of how to do this, it would be greatly appreciated!